# Layer error: Image.rename: The number of names (2) must match the number of bands (12)

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, density

I'm using landsat 9 raw data and get some topographic correction before, for canopy density mapping, after all band input to the equation for FCD there are error message appear, it said"Layer error: Image.rename: The number of names (2) must match the number of bands (12)."

Here's the code I used to:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3ca63e3bbeda2d1fd66a076f1f3d3275

and the first piece of code (line 161) where rename method appears.

```
// Subset the SWIR1 and IL. In the regression reducer, independent
// variables come first followed by the dependent variables. 
//In this case, IL is the independent variable and 
//B6 (SWIR1) is the dependent variable.
var imgRegress6 = illumination.select('slope')
  .addBands(ref.select('SR_B6'))
  .rename(['IL', 'l9_swir1']);
```

Comment: The rename in the piece of code you shared (line 161) *does* work, as there are only two bands in the image you are applying it ("slope" and "SR_B6"). Please provide a *minimal* reproducible example (*not* 700+ lines) where you have identified the error. Also, if the example requires access to one of your assets, make them public. In any case, the error is well explained -- there is an image with 12 bands and you are providing only two names to rename. You should provide 12 new band names.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 767 lines (including comments) and I think it is too long for considering all. So, I considered only debugging the first third. Issues appear mainly in blocks as the following where you rename inappropriately.

```
// Subset the SWIR1 and IL. In the regression reducer, independent
// variables come first followed by the dependent variables. 
//In this case, IL is the independent variable and 
//B6 (SWIR1) is the dependent variable.
var imgRegress6 = illumination.select('slope')
  .addBands(ref.select('SR_B6'))
  .rename(['IL', 'l9_swir1']);
.
.
.
var imgRegress5 = illumination.select('slope')
  .addBands(ref.select('SR_B5'))
  .rename(['IL', 'l9_NIR']);
```

More appropriate syntax would be as follows:

```
var illumination = (slope_rad.cos().multiply(SZA_rad.cos()))
           .add(slope_rad.sin().multiply(SZA_rad.sin())
           .multiply(SAA_rad.cos().subtract(aspect_rad).cos()))
           .rename('IL');
.
.
.
var imgRegress6 = illumination
  .addBands(ref.select('SR_B6').rename('l9_swir1'));
.
.
.
var imgRegress5 = illumination
  .addBands(ref.select('SR_B5').rename('l9_NIR'));
```

However, when you try to export to assets or Google Drive appear other problems and they can be solved with **bestEffort** parameter inside **reduceRegion** method. Assuming that **geomet** geometry is similar to **map_area**, [debugging code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/49526e3b7929f18a0f325a243f511b3b) produces the result of following picture:

[image]

At the above picture, layers and printed objects (Tab Console) were produced without any error. It can be also observed that **B5L9corectopo** and **B6L9corectopo** layers were also exported without any issues (with your original code it was not possible).